# How to use a custom controller method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I am trying to learn how to use a hyperlink in a view to access a custom controller method. I have the following code in my Controller, and I would like to access this with a `link_to` command in a View. I'm guessing there is something I need to do in the routes file to make the `launch_build_file` method work? What code should I list in the View to trigger the `launch_build_file` method?

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def launch_build_file
    Process.spawn("ruby #{Rails.root}/lib/build.rb")
  end

end
```

Comment: why you are spawning a ruby process?

Comment: I'm very new at learning Rails. I am sure there is a more graceful way of doing this in Rails - but as a first step, I want to be able to run an existing Ruby file by clicking on a link in a View in Rails.

In other words, rather than type `ruby build.rb' at the command prompt, I want to trigger the file to run by clicking on a link in the View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes file suppose you have reports resource,if not then you can use named routes

```
resources :reports do

 collection do
  get :launch_build_file
 end


end
#or
match '/reports/launch_build_file' => "reports#launch_build_file", :as => 'launch_build_file'

#If it's collection route 
link_to launch_build_file_reports_path
#or 
link_to launch_build_file_path
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried using the collection suggestion, and now I see an error saying:

'Missing template reports/launch_build_file, application/launch_build_file with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/rails_projects/av_reports_temp/app/views"'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `render :nothing=>true` or `redirect_to` some page

Answer (score 1):

```
link_to "foo", :controller => :reports, :action => :launch_build_file
```

Or you could make a named route and use that to get the URL.

Comment: Thank you. I'm starting to understand a little better now.